Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml for Next.js frontend and Node.js backend in one Docker image
I am trying to docker an image for my Node.js (backend) Next.js (frontend) project. In the build time, I expect the Next.js frontend to fetch a JSON file from the Node.js backend and generate static pages. However, it seems like the client side cannot resolve the host "backend" to fetch data from the server side.
UPDATE: I split the Dockerfile into 2 separate Dockerfile for client and server side. I also added a directory proxy which included its own Dockerfile and default.conf.
This is my ./client/Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.25
COPY --from=builder /app/.next /usr/share/nginx/html

This is my ./server/Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "dist/app.js"]

This is my ./proxy/Dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.25
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

This is my ./proxy/default.conf:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:80/;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend:5000/;
  }
}

This is my ./docker-compose.yml:
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./client
    ports: ['8001:80']
  backend:
    build: ./server
    ports: ['8002:5000']
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    ports: ['8000:80']

This is the error in log console:
34.47  ✓ Compiled successfully
34.47    Collecting page data ...
35.29 Error loading parts TypeError: fetch failed
35.29     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13484:13
35.29     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
35.29     at async s (/app/.next/server/pages/parts.js:1:8694)
35.29     at async d (/app/.next/server/pages/parts.js:1:13445)
35.29     at async buildStaticPaths (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:788:33)
35.29     at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1220:110
35.29     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20) {
35.29   [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
35.29       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1615:16) {
35.29     errno: -111,
35.29     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
35.29     syscall: 'connect',
35.29     address: '127.0.0.1',
35.29     port: 5000
35.29   }
35.29 }

Terminal command:
docker-compose up -d --build
Could someone tell me where I did wrong, please?

Your app will be returned to the client. and it will be the clients browser that will then try to resolve the http://backend but that wouldnt know what that is since your client browsers is not part of your docker network

For a quick fix on a local system only, you can set the URL the browser sees to http://localhost:5000/ to point directly at the backend container's published port, but this only works locally and triggers CORS rules.  In the linked question I describe how and why this happens in general and how to set up a reverse proxy to avoid the problem.

@DavidMaze I read your reply in the other post and your GitHub repository as well. I followed up on your instruction but it seemed the error still existed. Could you please look at my updated post and let me know where I did it wrong?
